# How many is too many columns (safely) in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am making an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that may end up having 400 - 500 columns of data. Will a large number of columns like that be unstable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just give you an experience. Excel 2010 files with more than 80Mb of size will not even be loaded by Excel.
Remember Excel 2010 uses OpenXML by default as its file format, but MS recommends you save the file as an Excel Binary Workbook (.xlsb) if you have too many formulas in your speedsheet.
So considering the number of the columns check out the size of the file, if is not big, i think there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 256 columns you won't be able to use versions of Excel prior to 2007. Stable is a bit more of a subjective term and will largely depend on the amount of memory that the viewers of this spreadsheet have. Personally I think from a user perspective 500 columns is too unwieldy but maybe that's just me.

Comment: This limitation was modified to 16k in Office 2007.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx

Comment: The other answers are technically correct but this makes the important point that sheets with too many columns are difficult to use.  Jonathan, are you sure that having this many columns is good design?

Comment: @jesse thank you. I edited the answer to reflect the 2007 vs 2010.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I was going to use a table of contents to navigate through the columns. I ended up going with a different solution because this one turned out to be a cumbersome mess.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential problems: Insufficient RAM and slow recalcs. The first is mainly a function of the total number of cells. 500 rows with 1 column won't be a problem. With a million, you'll need quite a bit of RAM...

Recalc speed will also vary with number of cells but just as much with the average complexity of the formulae. If it's just static data, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, you will not hit any column limits.

This link has an overview from Microsoft on the limitations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700514.aspx

The highlights are:

Columns: 16,384

Rows: over a million

The only limit you're likely to hit is a 2GB RAM limit for formulas if you're using 32 bit Excel.